# Polymorphic self application

Tags: haskell, lambda, system-f

I have an example of System F plymorphism that I don't really understand:
[image]

If I would remove the types it would remain:
\f.\a.f (f a) which makes no sense.

Can you help me with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The erased term does make sense: in Haskell it would be `\f a -> f (f a)`, a fairly ordinary function that applies its first argument to its second, and then again to the result.

The difference between `\f a -> <body>` and `\f.\a. <body>` is only one of notation. If you prefer, write the Haskell term `\f -> \a -> f (f a)`, which is equivalent but syntactically a bit closer to the erased System F.

(Note that `double` is not self application, which would be `\f -> f f`.)